# Windows 10: A Hotkey for editing file tags

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, tags

All I want is a keyboard shortcut to start editing a file's tags instead of going to the Details panel in properties.

Comment: Have you looked into something like AutoHotKey?

Comment: Alternatively, turn on the Details pane in Explorer and edit the details/tags in the side-bar.

Comment: @spikey_richie I did use the Details pane, but can't edit the tags directly from there.

Comment: @Ramhound No. I didn't know whether it was possible there. But maybe I should check.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are looking for a keyboard shortcut to take you from the file in file explorer directly to the Details Panel in Properties where you edit a file's tag. To do so, you can use 2 shortcuts in sequence.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open Properties

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to change panels.

So, from a selected file in File Explorer, you would hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. 
I was having in mind editing the tags directly from the Tag column in the Details view or some easier method. 
But this shortcut chain would do for now.

Comment: If you are looking for a more spreadsheet/excel-like editing experience for tags, you may have to look into third party software that's designed for the particular type of files you are tagging. Such as Mp3tag for music/media files.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the tags property in the details view, but not under the tags column. You can do it over in the right panel of the detail view. I think that's what spikey_richie meant by "side-bar" ... the panel all the way on the right of the screen. The left panel shows the file structure, the middle panel shows the file list in details view, and the right panel shows the file properties where the "tags" property can be edited very quickly and easily without all the clicks and shortcut keys. Just remember to hit enter or click save after changing the tag or your change will not be saved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).